# Is there an international database for stolen camera and lenses?

Tags: serial-number

I recently get robbed and I had many Nikon appliances stolen. 
The only way for the moment to recover them is to phone the Nikon company and declare the items stolen.

But that said, will they share these stolen serial numbers across all their countries? How can I be sure my camera will not be repaired in another country by an official Nikon service office?

Is there another way (like a public database not related to any brand) to share stolen items by their serial number?

Answer (score 3):

There are several databases, the most recent I've heard of is [Lenstag](https://www.lenstag.com/) (I'm not associated with it).
However, if you search Google you can find [several](http://www.stolen911.com/category/177/Stolen-Cameras-and-Photographic-Equipment.html) [other](http://photo.net/neighbor/registry/) databases as well. 
The existence of several databases undermines the usefulness of such a registration system as you would need to register with all of them, and also check all of them when buying second hand gear. I think that's not possible.
Moreover, most databases require that you register your gear when it's in your possession.

As far as I know there's little you can do after the theft.

Comment: and for good reason. Too easy for someone to "as a joke" add random serial numbers or serial numbers they got from the gear of people they've since fallen out with (think divorce...), and rightful owners ending up in trouble as a result.